# Crawling and validating JavaScript code in a web document

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, analytics

I am working on a project where I'm required to enforce a "no tampering with the analytics code" policy on webpages. Is it possible to enforce such a policy? I'm thinking it should be doable in the following way:

1. Crawl the webpage.
2. Check for places where said JavaScript code
   resides.
3. Check if the code is identical to what is expected.

Is that reasonable? Is there any way for someone to get around this policy? (I'm not concerned about the *ability* to tamper with the code, as long as I can detect that the code has been tampered with).

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the motivation behind the policy. What exactly is the objective of ensuring that client-side javascript is not tampered with? If your purpose is to provide a widget that can be deployed in a user's application, then crawling a client's page to examine the javascript is definitely feasible. It may be possible to trick your crawler by inserting dummy code that is not executed in all the right places. Seems like a strange request. Sorry if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks. It's not really for a "client" per se. I've come up with a ranking mechanism that takes into account the bounce rate. Therefore, for it to work, the bounce rate should not be tampered with.